# groovy convert String "1,503" to Integer

Tags: groovy

I'm parsing a file that has integer values using commas to separate thousands.

```
String s = "1,503"
Integer i = new Integer(s)
```

does not work, throws a parse exception.  Is there an easy way to parse this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NumberFormat` instead. For example, in Java:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(Locale.US);
        Long parsed = (Long) format.parse("1,234");
        System.out.println(parsed);
    }
}
```

(You can then get the integer value from the `Long`, of course.)

I've explicitly specified `Locale.US` to guarantee that comma is used as the thousands separator; you may want to use a different locale if the input can vary.

Answer (score 7):

A slightly more groovy method might be;

```
int a = java.text.NumberFormat.instance.parse( '1,234' )
```

But this will use the default locale